# Taskbar not working on Raspberrypi over xrdp

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspi-config

When connecting to the raspberry pi over XRDP the pi will not show the taskbar if the Pi is set to boot to cli by default however if I tell it in the raspi-config to boot to desktop it will let me XRDP in and show the taskbar.

Is they a fix to this other then having to tell the pi to log me in automatically ?

Comment: I am too facing this issue with XRDP but only after this (https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian) latest update to Raspberry Pi. Any suggestions for fix?

Answer (score -2):

You can find the solution in the last post of this link.
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=148030&p=974857

I was able to fix my same issue through it. Hope it helps you too.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.